# What is the correct way of using sinon spy restore or reset?

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, mocha.js, sinon, chai

I have a test suit with mocha, sinon and chai:

```
describe('general visor methods tests', () => {

    let res, req, next, resSpy, resNext;

    beforeEach(() => {
        res = {};
        next = () => {};
        resSpy = res.json = sinon.spy();
        resNext = next = sinon.spy();
    });
    afterEach(() => {
        resSpy.restore();
        resNext.reset();
    });


describe('get basemap layers from owner model', () => {
    it('should send the basemap provided by the owner model', () => {
        owner.basemap = ['basemap1', 'basemap2'];
        getBaseMapLayersFromConfig(req, res, next);
        //  console.log(resSpy.args[0][0].data);
        expect(resSpy.calledOnce).to.eql(true);
        expect(resSpy.args[0][0].message).to.eql('basemaps correctly found');
        expect(resSpy.args[0][0].data).to.eql(['basemap1', 'basemap2']);
    });

...
```

if I put `resSpy.reset()` it works fine. I've read that the reset() function is to reset the state of the spy.

But what i don't understand is that if i put resSpy.restore() then it thows the next error:

```
TypeError: resSpy.restore is not a function
```

I don't know what I'm doing wrong or what should be the correct way of using restore.

Also I don't quite know when should i use reset or restore.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

`spy.restore()` is only useful if you're using the following initialization:

```
let someSpy = sinon.spy(obj, 'someFunction');
```

This will *replace* `obj.someFunction` with the spy. If you ever want to go back to the original, you use `someSpy.restore()`.

You're using a standalone spy, so there's nothing to restore.

Also, because you're creating new spies for each test, in `beforeEach`, you don't have to reset anything in `afterEach`. That's only useful if you want to reuse the spies:

```
describe('general visor methods tests', () => {
  let someSpy = sinon.spy(); // create the spy once

  afterEach(() => {
    someSpy.reset(); // reset after each test
  });

  ...
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the insight into this detail/aspect. Learning something new each time I write tests, even on frameworks I thought I had plenty of mileage and good understanding of.